# Maximizing the Expectation on Multivariate Gaussians

Tags: probability, optimization, normal-distribution, expected-value

Say I have a sequence of gaussian random variables $(X_1, X_2, \dots)$ with mean $E[X_i]=\mu_i$ and $\text{Cov}(X_i,X_j)=E[X_iX_j]-\mu_i\mu_j=\rho_{ij}$.

Say I can pick $n$ variables in total.
Which variables $S\subseteq\{1,\dots\}$ should I pick to maximize $E[\max_{i \in S}(X_i)]$?

I could try to maximize a surrogate, like $\sum_{i\in S} \mu_i - \sqrt{\sum_{i,j} \rho_{i,j}}$, which would incentivize "diversification". However, I have no idea how to connect that to "the real" problem I'm interested in solving.

This seems like a problem that should be "Portfolio Selection Problems". Except that I'm interested in the maximum instead of the total.
Also in Portfolio problems you can weight each $X_i$ by a real value. I'm not sure if adding that option would make my problem easier or harder.